# How can i save pagination, sort, search state of a table in Angular 8? I am using angular2-datatable

Tags: angular, datatable, pagination, angular8, savestate

I have a table showing a list of items. I clicked on one item in page 3 and navigated to details page of that item. Now after completing task in details page when i navigate back to table page, i want to come in same page 3.
current behavior: it navigates to page 1.
Reading documentation of Data Tables, I found a property stateSave that saves states. How can i implement it in angular2-datatable?
I am using angular2-datatable for displaying items in table.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can resolve this I think.

- If you have a state management system you can save the current page in state
- you can include the page number in router.

I prefer the router way because whenever the URL refreshed or copy paste to another browser it will render the exact page.

```js
const route: Route = [
  {
    path: 'table/:pageNumber',
    component: TableComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'table/:pageNumber/item',
    component: ItemComponent,
  }
];
```

use `this.router.navigate(['table', 1]);` to initially load table

In TableComponent use the below to get the page number on `ngOnInit`

```js
class TableComponent implements ngOnInit() {
  activePage!: number;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activePage = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.pageNumber || 1;
  }
  
  onRowClick() {
   this.router.navigate(['table', this.activePage, 'item'])
  }
}
```

```html
<table ...
[mfActivePage]="activePage" (mfOnPageChange)="onPageChange($event)>
</table>
```

This is the whole idea, The router config and routing urls may vary according to you app. Please try this.

Comment: can u please make a demo  on stakbliz. I got bit confused as i am new to angular ... thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Tell me your doubt. I may be able to help with it.

Comment: thank you so much @JsNgian that helped a lot . i made a small modification. i added a click event on paginator and paginator is working fine. <td colspan="10">
                <mfBootstrapPaginator
                  [rowsOnPageSet]="[10, 25, 50]"
                  (click)="onPageChange(mf)"
                ></mfBootstrapPaginator>
              </td>. Now i want to add  [mfRowsOnPage]="10" its value dynamically. Can u please guide me once more... thank you

Comment: `(mfOnPageChange)="onPageChange($event)"` this event will give you `rowsOnPage` and `rowsOnPage`. use `[mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage"` (create a `rowsOnPage` variable in ts) and inside `onPageChange(event) { this.rowsOnPage = event.rowsOnPage; this.activePage = event.activePage }` This would work I guess. If you think this is the right answer please accept it as answer.

Comment: i am having an issue. if i  change RowsOnPage values( eg, it was at first 10 and then i changed  to 50 rows on page) and went to see details of one item from the page 5. After returning to list page ,all pagination( activePage) values resets to 1. I want it to preserve its rowOnPage to previous value 50 and page 5 . I printed on console, RowsOnPage and activePage shows correctly 50 and 5 which i have stored in a service , but active page shows 1 and sometimes 2 not correct active page 5. can u please help me to fix it... thanks in advance